# Checking if any input or textarea element in the page is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a mechanism in my website that's supposed to warn users whenever they are about to close a page they were working in. I'm binding a function `dropDraftConfirmation` to the [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event, like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = dropDraftConfirmation;

function dropDraftConfirmation()
{
    if (<there is an input or textarea element not empty on the page>) {
        alert('Your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit the page?');
    }
}
```

But this is called every time I close a page. So my question is, how to detect if there is an input or textarea element in the page that is *not* empty? I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
window.onbeforeunload = dropDraftConfirmation;

function dropDraftConfirmation()
{
    if ($("input:empty,textarea:empty").length == 0) {
        alert('Your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit the page?');
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using
`if ($('textarea').val() || $('input').val()) {
    alert(Your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit the page?)';
}`
But thanks

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your function like the one below to check any unsaved changes before unload

```
window.onbeforeunload = checkUnSaved;

function checkUnSaved(){
     if($("#textarea").val() === ""){
         dropDraftConfirmation();
     }else
         return;
}

function dropDraftConfirmation()
{
    if (<there is an input or textarea element not empty on the page>) {
        alert('Your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit the page?');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like:

```
var errors = 0;

    $("input, textarea").map(function(){
        var val = $.trim( $(this).val() );
        if( val.length < 1 ) {
           errors++;  
        }
    });

    if( errors > 0 ) {
        alert('Your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit the page?');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition will look like this:

```
if ($("input[value!='']").length > 0 || $('textarea:not(:empty)').length > 0 ){
```